# Check if the number is even or odd without using if else

Tags: operators

Enter an integer. Check if the number is even or odd
(using the ternary operator)

I can't solve this problem

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

```
let num = 3;
num % 2 == 1 ? console.log("odd"): console.log("even");
```

Comment: You should state (in the answer itself) what language this is.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const isEven = (value) => value % 2 === 0 ? true : false;
console.log(isEven(4));
console.log(isEven(7));
```